# K refers to a type but is being used as a value in type definition

Tags: typescript

Consider the following type:

```
type Test<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: typeof K;
}
```

Which gives the following error:

[image]

```
'K' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I know how to fix this, which is:

```
type DoMagic<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
}
```

and shouldn't this be:

```
type DoMagic<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: typeof T[K];
}
```

but this doesn't work (probably related to the first error).

But in the following example it does work:

```
const s = 'hello';
const n = 'world' as typeof s;
```

As you can see I'm a little bit confused here by `keyof` and `typeof`.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: You can't use typeof on types. You use typeof on objects to get their types. `K` and `T[K]` are types, `s` is a object.

Comment: For your `T[K]`, `T` is a type. And for the `type of s` in the last example, `s` is a variable, that's the difference.

Comment: Treat `keyof` like `Object.keys`. As you see they have nothing in common

Comment: Thnx for these comments, now I understand my confusion :)